# ajax in zend frame work

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

I am new to Zend Frame Work.
I am using $ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext'); for adding action contexts. I have one Index.phtml page and all other views are ajax.phtml pages. I have to do some java script methods in the ajax.phtml pages. But i didn't find a way to refer the js files in the ajax.phtml pages. I have tried adding those in the controller init and index action, using $this->view->headScript()->appendFile, though i have the reference added in the page source, none of htese seems to be working on the ajax content. Then i tried to add it in the action for the ajax page, then it is not coming in the page source itself. As far as i understood, $this->view->headScript()->appendFile will append the file reference to the layout page and for the ajax.phtml pages, the layout will be disabled. 
Is there any way that i can refer my js files in the ajax.phtml pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two ways to resolve this issue. One is we can bound the click event of the ajax postbacked content button with a jquery.live() method. This will register the element in the DOM, even if the element is not present at the time of page load. 
Another way is to reload the javascript in the success of each ajax postback using the getScript() method. In this way all the newly added elements will get registered and active. if you are using jquery dialogs, using variables, you may have to destroy those, before reloading the js.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right way, but where does you echo the ViewHelper?

After adding the Files with the headScript view Helper try:

```
echo $this->headScript();
```

Comment: That i am doing in the layout page

Comment: @rookie then try it in the ajax.phtml not your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code to your Controller public function:

```
public function indexController(){
  $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
  $Response = $this->getResponse();
  $Response->setBody(Zend_Json::decode($foo))
           ->setHeader('content-type', 'application/json', true);
return null;
}
```